# MapBox Geometry ID

Tags: mapbox, gis, geojson

I am exporting data from RideReport (https://public.ridereport.com/santa-monica) . The data is not complete if exported as GeoJSON. When I export the data as CSV it is complete but it has no geometry. However it has Geometry ID. I believe it has something to do with MapBox. I checked the website source. Apparently, they are using a GeoJSON code that has ID and someother attributes [count and prectenagematched]

[image]

My question is how can I extract the geometry to be used in QGIS from the geometry id?

Thanks.

Comment: How is the GeoJSON data not complete? The GeoJSON data looks complete and is visible in geojson.io. The CSV looks like a table that you may need to join to existing line geometries.

Answer (score 0):

After checking with RideReport, the geometry ids are corresponding to SharedStreets, so using the SharedStreet Python module, I could extract a `geojson` file that has both geometry and id.

Sharedstreets data can be extracted through:
https://github.com/sharedstreets/sharedstreets-python

Other languages also exit. Then, using the extracted data you can match 'Shared Geometry ID' with the one you have extracted

Comment: This seems like a useful direction. Could you [edit] your answer to provide more details about your solution? That will help future readers with a similar problem.